# How to custom EditTextStyle

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-theme

I have this code in my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bioresult.geopointer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/geopointer_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.bioresult.geopointer.activity.LoginActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">         
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.bioresult.geopointer.activity.homeActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/geopointer"
            android:label="">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.bioresult.geopointer.activity.registraPosizioneActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">            
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.bioresult.geopointer.activity.salvaAreaTracciataActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >            
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.bioresult.geopointer.activity.settingActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">            
        </activity>
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCFoFJXG0KeXg40rbxIItCQ0KM0G6S91wI"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the code of my Stle.xml

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">

    </style>

    <style name="CustomEditTextStyle"  parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>


</resources>
```

I want with this code, see the template of application like as Theme.Holo but I want the style of EditText like as another template. So this code not works. I try to set manually of all edittext the template Theme.NoTitleBar but not works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<resources>

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.EditText</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

The only thing you have to do is finding the correct android::style. A list of all styles can be found here: [Android API R.style](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html)

By changing the style of your `AppTheme` all Edittexts will look like the newly defined style

Comment: I try to use your code, but the result is the same.

Comment: Hmm, this 'should' work :) I think I need more details. Let me recapitulate your problem: You want to use your theme "AppTheme". But your edittext should be from another theme. The code I posted should solve this problem. What else I am seeing in your posted code: some activities are using their own theme, and not the "application theme". Is this correct? And do you only have one style.xml or different style.xml for the different versions (e.g. in values-14)?